# using .ttf with latex/texstudio - NO XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX

Tags: fonts, pdftex, miktex, truetype

before I get started, I want to apologize for asking this question one more time. But I did not find any suitable answer honestly.

I would like to use .ttfs which I posses. There does not seem to be any easy way but I dont even get the hard way to work. 
Using TexStudio pdftex with MikTeX I am looking for a way to create and use .tfm-files. According to this [link](https://www.tug.org/fonts/fontinstall.html) it is possible, but only if there are .map-files provided. This is not the case.

Is there any tutorial to get .ttfs running for texstudio or should I stick to other fonts?
Thanks for any help, link or answers in advance!

Comment: Why don't you use XeLaTex/LuaLaTeX?

Comment: The map-files are simple txt files and easily writen. The hard bit are the tfm, vf and fd-files. See e.g. for the first step: https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb30-1/tb94thanh.pdf.

Comment: It's not impossibly difficult but it is not that easy and there is very little current experience that you can use to get help because it is so much easier to use xetex or luatex than to make ttf available to pdftex that few people do it now.

Comment: For many fonts somebody around the world has already distilled all the necessary files, you only need to buy the fonts itself and install it with these files. If you edit your question and provide the name of the fonts, maybe somebody can help.